# Problema con Arrays (estudiante)

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Soy estudiante y no consigo hacer que funcione este código.
Creo que el problema viene con el manejo de Arrays pero no consigo saber porque no funciona.

```
  public class A1IntroduirDNI {
    static int MAXDNI = 10;
    String[] dniLista = new String[MAXDNI];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dniActual;
    boolean repetit = false;
    int comptador = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //adapteu la instanciació del programa d'acord amb el fitxer on treballeu
        A1IntroduirDNI prg = new A1IntroduirDNI();

        prg.inici();
    }

    //Programa principal. Anirà demanat dni's fins que introduint un 0 o omplint l'array de 10 posicions
    private void inici(){

            //todo 
 //            do {   
                demanarDNI();

//            } while (dniLista.length < MAXDNI );

    }

    //Aquesta funció demana un DNI  i si l'entrada és buida dona un missatge, no deixa entrar valors buits. El dni es guardarà a una variable global

    private void demanarDNI(){

            System.out.print("Entra el dni ");
            dniActual = scan.nextLine();
           if (dniActual.compareTo("0") != 0) {
                //buscar dni
              buscarDNI();
                //si trobem dni mostrar dni repetit
               if (repetit == true) {
                    System.out.println("DNI repetit");
              }else{
                     //sino afegir dni y aunmentar numero del comptador

                    dniLista[comptador] = dniActual;
                   comptador++;  
                }
            }

        }

    //Funció que busca si el dni introduït està repetit, si el troba haurà de marcar una variable  indicant que ha trobat el dni 
    private void buscarDNI(){

            for (int j = 0; j < dniLista.length; j++) {

                int result = dniLista[j].compareTo(dniActual);

                if (result == 0) {
                    repetit = true;
                }
            }
    }

    //mostra tots els dni's de l'array
    private void mostrarArrayDNI(){
        for (int i = 0; i < dniLista.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(dniLista[i]);
                }
                //mostrar array
    }

}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema? que hace el codigo? que deberia hacer? cual es la salida esperada? cual es la sailda que recibis? que parte del codigo no hace lo que deberia hacer? Todo eso tenes que revisar para ver que le pasa a tu codigo y te podamos ayudar. Asi como esta la pregunta no permite que te ayudemos. El titulo tambien debe ser significativo sobre el problema que tenes.

Comment: Por favor primero lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y  con gusto te ayudará.